Any periodic point has period q.
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Show that if $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is a homeomorphism with rational rotation number $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime positive integers, then any periodic point has period $q.$
Some thoughts:
I was able to show that any point has period a multiple of $q.$ but I am not sure how to show that the only periodic points of $f^q$ are fixed points. Do we have to show some lifting?
Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

do you mean 'any periodic point has period a multiple of $q$'? and have you yet shown that such points always exist?

yes for your first question and no for your second one @Nalline

As $f$ is a homeomorphism on the circle it lifts to some homeomorphism $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ satisfying $F(x+\ell)=F(x)+\ell$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and $\ell \in \mathbb Z$. By lift here, we mean that if $\pi:\mathbb R\to S^1$ is given by $x\mapsto x\mod 1$, then $f\circ \pi =\pi\circ F$.
Thus, if $z\in S^1$ is a periodic point of $f$ with period $k$, we can consider $z$ as a point in the unit interval, so $\pi \circ F^k(z) =z$. Therefore,  $F^k(z)=z+m$ for $m\in \mathbb Z$. Furthermore, as $F$ is a lift, this means that, for any $\ell\in\mathbb N$, $F^{\ell k}(z)=z+\ell m$. Now, by the definition of the rotation number we know that, for any $x\in \mathbb R$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F^n(x)-x}{n}=\frac{p}{q},$$
which means this limit must be the same along any subsequence. Particularly, it means that
$$\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{F^{\ell k}(z)-z}{\ell k}=\frac{p}{q},$$
but from above, this means that
$$\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{\ell m}{\ell k}=\frac{p}{q}.$$
This means that $\frac{m}{k}=\frac{p}{q},$ meaning that $k=nq$, and $m=np$ for some integer $n$, because $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Now, all that is left to show is that if $z$ is a periodic point of $f$ with period $nq$ for some natural number $n$, then it is also a periodic point with period $q$.
Suppose by way of contradiction that $z$ is a periodic point of $f$ with period $nq$ as above, but $F^q(z)\neq z+p$. We may as well assume that $F^q(z)>z+p$. Recall that, because $F$ is a homeomorphism, it must be monotone. Thus,
$$F^{2q}(z)>F^q(z+p)=F^q(z)+p>z+2p.$$
Carrying on recursively $n$ times leads to the conclusion that
$F^{nq}(z)>z+np$, which is a contradiction. Thus $F^{q}(z)=z+p$, but by definition of a lift this means that $f^q(z)=z$, so indeed $z$ has period $q$.

are you assuming that $q>p$?

@Intuition As the lift $F$ is unique modulo 1, as is the circle rotation number, that is generally assumed. However that assumption is not needed in my proof.

I did not understand your idea of proving "Why the only periodic points of $f^q$ are fixed points. "

@Intuition What don't you understand? I first show that the only periodic points of $f$ have to have period $nq$. I then assume that if a point $x$ is a periodic point of period $nq$ it isn't actually periodic with period $q$, and arrive at a contradiction. Thus $x$ must be periodic with period $q$.

Can you please state clearly what is the idea of the contradiction you reached at the end also?

how did you show that "it isn't actually periodic"? What stopped it from being periodic with period q? Recall that in my main statement of the problem at the end I said we want to conclude that "any periodic point has period q"

Also, I did not get why $q > p$ is an implicit assumption here (I understand that you did not use it here, I just want to know out of curiosity)?

Why there is a contradiction of a point being a fixed point and periodic point at the same time?

also, I see you that you are mostly ignoring the function $\pi$ you mentioned in your first paragraph, is there a reason for that or I am missing something?

Also, why $k = nq$ for some natural number n and not an integer n? I see in your second paragraph your m was an integer.

@Intuition I never stated that "it isn't actually periodic". I prove that if $z$ is a periodic point, then it must have period $nq$. I then prove that if a point $z$ has period $nq$, it must actually have period $q$. This directly answers your main question. $\pi$ is important because it is crucial to the definition of a lift. The definition of a circle rotation number means that it is unique on $\mathbb R /\mathbb Z$, so basically by definition it is in the unit interval.

In fact I prove something further. I show that if $z$ has period $nq$, then $F^{nq}(z)=z+np$. I then show if if $F^q(z)\neq z+p$, then $F^{nq}(z)\neq z+np$. Thus if $z$ is a periodic point of $f$ it must satisfy $F^q(z)=z+p$, but $\pi\circ F^q(z)=f^q\circ \pi(z)$, so $f^q(z)=z$, which by definition means $z$ has period $q$.

you said that in your second comment

your last comment is very clear thank you!
